# Windows phone image zoom

Tags: scroll, windows-phone, zooming

I used kendo mobile application to zoom image on windows phone.

Source code :

```
 <div data-role="view" data-zoom="true">
   <div>
    <div data-role="scroller" id="zoomable-explanation" style="text-align: center;">
      <p>The contents of this mobile view are zoomable using pinch/zoom gestures.</p>
      <p>
        Open on a mobile device, which supports <i>multi-touch</i> gestures.
        <br/>(iOS 4+, Android 4+ and Windows Phone 8)
      </p>
    </div>
    <img src="images/ice.png" style="display: block;margin: auto;"/>
  </div>
</div>

 var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
```

I am able to zoom image but I am not able to show all zoom image.